# Как вернуть данные из $http() в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
    user = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      data : user,
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth-user'
    }).then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data);//Object { id: 1, name: "gman", password: "281288", mail: "gman@mail.ru", avatar: null, role: "USER" }
          return response.data;
    });
    console.log(user); //Object { $$state: Object }
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Как все-таки вернуть данные из promise

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Все так.

`$http` - возвращает *promise*, и работать напрямую с результатом можно в функции `then`.

```
user = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      data : user,
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth-user'
    }).then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data);//Object { id: 1, name: "gman", password: "281288", mail: "gman@mail.ru", avatar: null, role: "USER" }
          return response.data;
    });

user.then(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;        
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно вот так:

```
    function service_func(data, callback) {
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/auth-user', data)
            .then(function(res){
                callback(res.data);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
```